# Why API method never fired?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I have this API methods:

```
namespace Playground.Web.Controllers.API
{
    public class FilterConfigurationsController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly PlaygroundContext _context;
        public FilterConfigurationsController()
        {
            _context = new PlaygroundContext();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Filter data)
        {
            try
            {
                var ere = FilterViewModel.GenerateDataForFilters(data, _context);
                return Ok(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(IEnumarable<Filter> filterDescriptionList)
        {
            try
            {
                var data = FilterViewModel.GenerateDataForFilters(filterDescriptionList, _context);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

To call this methods I use this HTTP post calls:

```
$http.post(config.baseUrl + "api/FilterConfigurations/", scope.filterParams).then(function (result) {});
```

I am working on web API project and using AngularJS in my project.

This HTTP post call:

```
$http.get(config.baseUrl + "api/FilterConfigurations/,{data= scope.filterParams[0]}).then(function (result) {});
```

have to call this method API:
   public async Task Post(Filter data)en(function (result) {});

But the method API above never fired.

Instead this method alwaes fired:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Filter filterDescriptionList)
```

Any idea why the API method never fired?
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no end quotation after the url in the $http.post ? You are also using GET not post.

Comment: there shouldn't be a trailing slash either

Comment: Why have you got two `[HttpPost]` attributes in your webapi controller, webapi works on the RESTful principle, so one of each: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT

Comment: Alternative: using server side routing with `[Route]` and remove the ambiguity of two similar-looking POST requests.